# The sequence S:=(sin n) is divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've seen its proof in Bartle and Sherbert.

But, I think a lot more interesting proofs of this can be done.
Plz, help me in writing its proof in other possible ways. So, that I can develop more constructive ideas for building proofs of such type in future.

Thanks in advance.
Plz write.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you sketched the proof you are familiar with.

Comment: Plz write the proof of this by your way.

Comment: The sequence $\sin n$ has infinite many limit numbers,  so there is no limit actually...

Answer (score 1):

Prove that $ \sin n$, $\sin (n+1)$ and $\sin (n+2)$ are not all close together.

Comment: This is a little terse, and looks at first glance to be a non-answer & hence deletable.  Can you flesh your  argument out a little, please?